# Mysql Concatenate 2 Calulcated fields into 1 column?

Tags: mysql

Good morning,
Is it possible to concatenate 2 calculate fields into 1 column? For each month of the year I have 2 columns, 1 outputs sales amount & the other sales numbers for each month;

January_£ | January Cases
£8,123.00 | 100

What I would like to do is to concatenate these into 1 column;
January
100 - £8,123.00

I have tried many methods & can concatenate 2 standard fields but cant seem to get the format correct for calculated fields? Columns in query at present;

```
  Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 1, b.CaseCommission, 0)) As January_£,
  Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 1) As January,
```

And my latest effort which doesnt work but also doesn't error!

```
CONCAT(Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 1, b.CaseCommission, 0)),Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 1)0 As January,
```

If anyone can confirm its possible to achieve this I would appreciate it.

Regards

gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 1), '-',
       Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 1, b.CaseCommission, 0)) ) AS January;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CONCAT(Sum(If(Month(b.CaseDate) = 1, b.CaseCommission, 0)),'-',
       Sum(Month(b.CaseDate) = 1)) As January,
```

Comment: That's great, thank you for your time it is much appreciated, I tried to set both answers as accepted as they were both posted at same time & correct but wouldn't allow.

Gary